# Numero aleatorio en MySQL que no se repita

Tags: mysql

Tengo el siguiente problema.

Necesito hacer que mi ***select*** se me genere de forma aleatoria, pero sin que se me repita.

Tengo colocada una expresión en el ***order by***, y sin embargo igual se me repite.

**Consulta:**

```
SELECT preguntas.* FROM preguntas ORDER BY rand() LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Contando la llave tiene 7 columnas

Comment: Si en un orden aleatorio y que no se repita

Comment: Se supone que esa consulta la usas para obtener una sola pregunta?

Comment: Si es correcto  solo un elemento

Comment: ahhhh espera me parece que estas preguntando mal.. un elemento distinto a los elementos que aparecieron antes?

Comment: ¿lo necesitas con mysql puro?

Comment: No necesariamente puede ser con php también

Comment: Perdón un pregunta tengo mar formulada la pregunta por favor dígamelo y la re formulo pero no  entiendo porque me la marca como una mala pregunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mira. Si solo quieres obtener solo un elemento, es difícil que no se repitan. Las posibles soluciones que se me ocurren son:

- Haces la consulta con la lista de preguntas que ya hiciste con

  ```
  SELECT preguntas.* 
  FROM preguntas 
  WHERE preguntas.id NOT IN(1,4,6) 
  ORDER BY rand() 
  LIMIT 1;
  ```

  donde 1, 4, 6 son las preguntas que ya se hicieron.
- Determinas la lista de preguntas desde antes, de forma que no se repitan, Algo como `ids de preguntas que se harán = {1,5,78,3,34,4,5,73}` usando la misma consulta que tu tienes:

  ```
  SELECT preguntas.* 
  FROM preguntas 
  ORDER BY rand() 
  LIMIT 10;
  ```

  Donde 10 es la cantidad total de preguntas que quieres para el Quiz o lo que estés haciendo.

Para ambos casos puedes guardar la lista en la sesión de usuario. Un ejemplo con datos fijos en PHP:

```
$_SESSION['preguntas'] = array (1, 6, 4, 12);

// dependiendo de tu marco de trabajo quedaría algo como 
$_SESSION['preguntas'] = Preguntas::getRandomQuestions(10);
```

Entonces en el caso primero, añades preguntas al array, en el segundo caso necesitaras otra variable adicional indicando en cual pregunta está. De todas formas si las respuestas de los usuarios se guardan en la base de datos, quizá solo necesites hacer otra consulta para verificar en cual pregunta se encuentra el usuario.

Bueno, lo pongo como respuesta, ya que lo había puesto como comentario :P

Answer (score 0):

Pero qué quieres que sea aleatorio, ¿las columnas o las filas?. Hice una prueba rápida en mi BD local y el utilizar `ORDER BY rand()` funciona de maravilla. ¿Cuál es el comportamiento que estás esperando?

```
select tabla.* from tabla order by rand();

+-------+
| campo |
+-------+
| b     |
| a     |
| c     |
| d     |
+-------+
```

y si lo corro de nuevo

```
+-------+
| campo |
+-------+
| d     |
| c     |
| a     |
| b     |
+-------+
```

Y en caso de que quieras sólo un registro también funciona tu código

```
select tabla.* from tabla order by rand() limit 1;
+-------+
| campo |
+-------+
| b     |
+-------+
```

de nuevo

```
+-------+
| campo |
+-------+
| c     |
+-------+
```

Comment: Lo que me sucede es que es una base de pregunta que se generan aleatorias pero que no se puede repetir y lo que me sucede es que me la esta repitiendo no me sucede siempre pero me pasa y no se me puede repetir

Comment: Hasta donde yo entiendo LIMIT 1 lo que hace es darte el primer registro del query que acabas de ejecutar. Por lo que puede ser que una misma base de pregunta pueda ser más de una vez el primer registro. Con SQL no se me ocurre una solución para tu problema, podrías tratar de guardar una lista de base de preguntas que ya hayan sido seleccionadas y cuando selecciones una nueva verificar que una nueva base no se encuentre en la lista. Espero que encuentres la solución (:

Comment: Ok muchas gracias creo que voy a tener que guardar los datos que ya use para editar que se me repitan muchas gracias